# Back from the application by pressing back button

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, onbackpressed

I am working on xamarin.forms application.I am calling page renderer form main page, from that page renderer I am navigating to activity like

```
    Android.App.Application.Context.StartActivity(new Intent(Android.App.Application.Context, typeof(Test)));
```

My requirement is when I press on back button I want to come back from the application.If I use OnBackPressed in Test activity like

```
    public override void OnBackPressed()
    {
        Finish();
    }
```

It is coming back from  Test activity and showing page renderer.If I use

```
    Android.OS.Process.KillProcess(Android.OS.Process.MyPid());
```

It is closing the application and stops the debugging.Please help me how to to come back from the application on pressing back button in Test activity.

Comment: So what exactly do you want from us your question is still quite ambiguous

Comment: Are you starting a *new* Activity within a custom view renderer? (if so, that should really be done via a dependency service call...)

Comment: hi @SushiHangover yes, I am starting a new Activity in Custom renderer